# My table is not populating correctly

Tags: php, mysqli, html-table

I was trying to grab everything from my MYSQL table then throw it all into a table. For some reason, it's throwing it all into one row instead of creating new rows for more data.

I have my code here:

```
 <?php
        //DISPLAY CURRENT USERS ASC ON VIEW
        $q="SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id ASC";
        $r=mysqli_query($dbc,$q);

        ?>

<div class="panel panel-default">
  <!-- Default panel contents -->
  <div class="panel-heading">User Manager</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <p>Some default panel content here. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
  </div>

  <!-- Table -->
<div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>UserID</th>
                  <th>First Name</th>
                  <th>Last Name</th>
                  <th>Email</th>
                  <th>Status</th>
                  <th>Role</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <?php  echo "<tr>"; // Display Users onto table
    while (($list= mysqli_fetch_assoc($r))){
            echo"<td>".$list['id']."</td>";
            echo"<td>".$list['fname']."</td>";
            echo"<td>".$list['lname']."</td>";
            echo"<td>".$list['email']."</td>";
            echo"<td>".$list['status']."</td>";
            echo"<td>".$list['role']."</td>";

    }
                echo"</tr>";?>       

              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>

</div>
```

Comment: <tr> tag (that is row tag) should be also in loop.

Comment: And take out `<tr>` and `</tr>` outside the loop.

Comment: Thanks everyone that fixed it. Sorry for the delay been away from coding for a bit. Appreciate all your help!

Answer (score 1):

All the `TR` tags are out of loop.

Answer (score 1):

It seems inside the while loop you need to start with

```
echo "<tr>";
```

and 
end with

```
echo "</tr>;
```

Now you are doing this only once